# Alert user upon cancelation in JSP/Spring MVC?

Tags: jquery, jsp, spring-mvc

So I'm using Errors to validate information in my Spring MVC and ran into something that I wanted feedback on how others do it, as I don't really do much web programming.

What's the best way to alert a user that if they cancel, they will lose information? What I'm looking for is a way to use a have it come back to my Model and check to see if any changes were made, and if so prompt the user to either stay on the page or lose the changes.

Is there an easy way to do this that might be Spring MVC Friendly or is the best way using JavaScript?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'd like to hook on the `beforeunload` event. This get invoked right before the page get unloaded because the user closes the browser tab/window, or navigates away by a link/bookmark, or submits the form. Just hooking on the `click` event of the cancel button doesn't cover all those cases.

Here's a kickoff example:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    // Set the unload message whenever any input element get changed.
    $(':input').change(function() {
        setConfirmUnload(true);
    });

    // Turn off the unload message whenever a form get submitted properly.
    $('.submit').click(function() {
        setConfirmUnload(false);
    });
});

function setConfirmUnload(on) {
    var message = "You have unsaved data. Are you sure to leave the page?";
    window.onbeforeunload = (on) ? function() { return message; } : null;
}
```

To get it to work properly, add `class="submit"` to the real submit button.

Comment: That would work nicely. The person working on the project with me has some qualms about doing the input function you have there, they want it to be able to do a more line-by-line check by our spring model(so that if the user undoes the change they made it'll not trigger an effect). Do you know of any spring friendly way?

Comment: Sorry, I don't do Spring, so I can't answer that from top of head.

Comment: I didn't expect you too... Just had to ask. Thanks for the above though.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the Onclick function and configure your message, alert the users as they loose the information if OnClick of cancel